Is there any way to solve this problem combinatorically or any other quick method?


Let $A$ = $\left\{ 2 , 3 , 6 , 7 \right\}$ and $B = \left\{ 4 , 5 , 6 , 8 \right\}$ .
Let $R$ be a relation defined on $A \times B$ by
$$
\left( a_{1} ,   b_{1} \right) R \left( a_{2} ,   b_{2}\right)\quad\mbox{if and only if}\quad
a_1 + a_2 = b_1 + b_2
$$
Then find the number of elements in  $R$.


$\rule{10cm}{0.5mm}$

I know we can solve this problem by listing out all the elements and relations which have a common sum.
What I wish to know is if there is a more elegant way to solve this problem.
I tried using PnC but was unable to make a general way for all the different cases.

Please elaborate if there is a better way to solve this problem.

I suspect that the problem composer's intent is that you forgo elegance, and simply track down the possibilities.  So, the first question that I suspect that the problem composer intended you to pursue is: of the $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2} = 6~$ (not necessarily distinct) possible sums of form $~(a_1 + a_2),~$ which of them intersect the corresponding possible sums $~(b_1 + b_2)?$

It doesn't help much in this example, but you can count the number of ways to get each sum out of two elements of $A$ and also $B$.  If the two numbers are different, count each order separately, so to get $12$ from $B$ there are three ways, $6+6, 4+8, 8+4$.  In this case few of them will match up because the elements of $B$ are rather larger than the elements of $A$.  For each sum that matches you can multiply the number of ways to get it from $A$ by the number of ways to get it from $B$.  Add up all the products and you are done.
